# Startup on AD authentication and user listing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, active-directory

I have 2 questions

I am new to C# and I am using VS2005.

Currently I am using ASP.NET Configuration tool for my Login form of my web application, thus the list of users are virtually created in the tool itself, not the actual users from the ActiveDirectory

---

**Q1.**

**Now I need to implement AD authentication in VS2005 but I have no clue on how should I start on it.**

**I would like to ask if there are any step by step guides on AD Authentication in VS2005 C#?**

---

I am also trying to implement user management in my web application. I would like to have a list of users retrieved from the ActiveDirectory as well as their groups, so that users in the administrator group will be able to manage the users.

---

**Q2.**

**How do I retrieve the list of users from the AD and list them in my web forms?**

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx) will answer both your questions.

It shows you how to set-up the Web.Config for your ASP.NET application and how to retrieve user information from the domain.